# detect touch on a view behind another view?

Tags: objective-c

I have two views

- the top view has some opaque and some transparent regions
- the bottom view has some clickable buttons.

The top view is completely covering the bottom view, but since top view has transparent areas, bottom view can still be seen.

BUT, i cannot detect button clicks on the bottom view anymore since topview is blocking it, what should I do?

Is there anyway to let top view pass the touches to bottom view?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My solution for my own question, hope it helps someone.

In the front view, listen for `touchesEnded:withEvent` delegate.

When this delegate fires, you knows that a user is touching the front view.

Next you need to check whether the finger position touches special areas in the BOTTOM view.

What to do is:

1) Convert the point to relative to the bottom view:

```
UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
CGPoint touchPointInLowerView = [touch locationInView:self.lowerViewController.view];
BOOL isLowerButtonClicked = [self.lowerViewController isFingerOnYourButton:touchPointInLowerView];
if(isLowerButtonClicked)
{
 // lower button clicked
}
```

2) In the lower view

```
- (BOOL) isFingerOnYourButton:(CGPoint)point
{
 return CGRectContainsPoint(self.aButton.frame, point);
}
```

voila. In this way, we can detect clicks in bottom view even it is blocked by another interactive view on top.

Comment: I need to do this, but I don't understand how to: Listen for touches ended:withEvent delegate, etc with a subclassed view. Call me whatever, but I need to see all of it.

Answer (score 3):

Turn off user interaction in the top view that is blocking the view underneath:

```
topView.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want the top view (or any of its subviews) to respond to touches at all, you can set the `userInteractionEnabled` property to NO for that view and be done with it.

Otherwise, your best bet is to override `pointInside:withEvent:` or `hitTest:withEvent:` in the top view's class. If the top view and the bottom view are siblings, it should enough to return NO from `pointInside:withEvent:`; if they are further separated in the view hierarchy, you may have to override `hitTest:withEvent:` to explicitly return the bottom view for the transparent areas.

Comment: unfortunately top view is a scrollable view... interaction is needed. I will look into your second proposal...thanks..will update it i got anything. meanwhile anyone has other suggestions do let me know.