# Get Touches in SuperView after adding SubView

Tags: objective-c, ios

Starting from the Single View iOS template in XCode 4.2, I've added a second view to my .xib, a 'Super' button on the main View, and a 'Sub' button on the subView. I'd like to be able to click both buttons.

In the view controller's interface, I've added:

```
IBOutlet UIView *subView;
```

Then in my view controller's viewDidLoad method, I add:

```
 [self.view addSubview:subView];
```

after [super viewDidLoad];

The subView has a background of 'clear', and both windows are set to 'User Interaction Enabled'.

When I run the application, only the 'Sub' button is clickable. I can see the 'Super' button, but it does not seem to be receiving touches, which should be the default behavior as far as I can tell from Apple's documentation (transparent areas of a view should allow touches to go through).

Answer (score 3):

This is not what happen, if you put a view in front of another, the view in the back will not receive the touch.

You can disable the user interaction in the fron view, so the backview will receive the touch.

but I think you want the frontview and the backview clickable, what do you need to do in this case is get the touch and send it to the backview, and handle it in the backview.

I do not know what you are trying to do, but I think, you probably can made a best option than that.

You can take a look at this question here in stackoverflow:
[detect touch on a view behind another view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6911721/detect-touch-on-a-view-behind-another-view)

EDIT:

You have a lot of options to send the touchs.

You can do something like (it is not a good option):

```
-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    for (UITouch *touch in touches) {        
        for(UIView* v in self.view.subviews){
            if([v pointInside:[touch locationInView:self.view] withEvent:event]){
                if ([v isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) {
                    [(UIButton*)v sendActionsForControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
                }

            }
        }
    }    
}
```

You also can edit the view frame so that the view will not cover the button.

You also can bring you button to the front of the new subview doing something like:

```
[self.view addSubview:yourSubview];
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:yourButton];
```

You just need to use your creativity ;)

Answer (score 0):

is your second view the size of the content (the button) or the size of the entire view? you may find it easier to just make your subview the size of the object, rather than 320x480. then align it via cgrectmake after adding it as a subview.

that's /way/ easier than bubbling the various touches, which becomes a bit of a nightmare.

Comment: It's the size of the entire view. For this project, making it a small view will work, though I'd love to learn how to properly bubble the touches up for full-screen overlays.